# How to mock a property using NSubstitute while using a real implementation

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have some NHibernate repositories and I would like my SpecFlow tests to cover them.

I have a repository for Staff like so:

```
public class StaffRepository : NHibernateRepository<IStaff>, 
{
    public IEnumerable<IStaff> GetByStaffId(string staffId)
    {
        return Repository.Where(ab => ab.StaffId == staffId);
    }
}
```

Where `Repository` is a property that lives on the base type - this is the property I would like to mock. I am using structure map to inject all my classes, and then mocking the StaffRepository like so:

```
pmsRepository = Substitute.For<StaffRepository>();
ApplicationContext.Register<IStaffRepository, StaffRepository>(pmsRepository);
```

My problem is, when I mock the `Repository` property like so:

```
pmsRepository.Query.Returns(ListOfStaffes.AsQueryable());
```

I always receive the following error message:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException: 'Could not find a call to return from.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. The `Repository` must be virtual or abstract; changing this to virtual resolved the issue.